# Auto Layout ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I have a `UIVIewController`- `VC_1`. I have two subViews `SubV_1` and `SubV_2`.

Frame of `SubV_1` is `(0,0,375,144)`.

I want to place `SubV_2` at position `(0,144,300,375)`, just below `SubV_1`.

I need to add 'Auto Layout' constraints such that when `SubV_1` is resized (decrease of height), then `SubV_2` is moved up automatically.

How do I do this using constraints programmatically?

Comment: Like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34651420/3222713 replace constant 0 by your value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)